# Notable to link javascript object and angularjs in controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to develop a mobile application in which i am getting JSON object using javascript page main.js,now I am trying to print the object using angualjs Controllers,but could not find any way.CAn anyone help me out on this?

function written in Main.js`

```
function getViewColumnsSuccess(result){ 
 var httpStatusCode = result.status;
    if (200 == httpStatusCode) { 
     var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
  var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
   if (true == isSuccessful) {
   var result = invocationResult.text; //var FinalCol=reult;
       } else {
    alert("Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode); } } }
```

The var result I want to get in DemoController in another page

```
app.controller('tableCtrlNew', function($scope,$http) { });
```

Comment: function written in Main.js.............................................

function getViewColumnsSuccess(result){
 var httpStatusCode = result.status;
 if (200 == httpStatusCode) {  
  var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
  var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
  if (true == isSuccessful) {
   var result = invocationResult.text;
   
 //var FinalCol=reult;
   }
 else {
  alert("Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode);
 }
 }  
}
****************
The var result I want to get in DemoController in another page
app.controller('tableCtrlNew', function($scope,$http) {
 
 
});

Answer (score 0):

First controllers are not for print data, for that you should dataBinding, in views.

For Example:
In your controller you have this var;

`$scope.name="John Doe";`

So, then to print that in some view, you shoud print that in some view that has that scope, so to print in one view(html) that is simple like:

```
<span class="labelName"> {{name}}</span>
```

It is data-binding, with this you automatically print data from a controller into a view, but remember, it  must be in the same scope to works.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Assign Result to Window object

```
window.result = invocationResult.text;
```

In controller you can use $window

```
app.controller('tableCtrlNew', function($scope,$http,$window) {
console.log($window.result);
 });
```